# getContentStream CMIS rest

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest, cmis

I'm trying to retrieve the content Stream of a document with CMIS rest protocol on SharePoint 2013. But I don't know what to send in the request.
This is the EndPoint:

```
http://server/subsite/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/repo_id?getContentStream
```

When I'm doing this, I get a message that told me too precise the objectId parameter so I add the parameter like this

```
http://server/subsite/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/repo_id?getContentStream?objectId=18-512
```

and I get this message

> "No service point is mapped to the request."

Does somebody know I to do to use this rest service?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getContentStream** used to Get the content stream for the specified Document object, or gets a rendition stream for a specified rendition of a document or folder object.

To can `getContentStream` you should pass the `objectid` parameters using **&** not **?** as the following:

```
http://Qassasserver/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/repo_id?getContentStream&objectid={your object id}
```